# How to set uncaugthExceptionHandler for all threads in Android app? Crash happens only on some cases

Tags: java, android, flutter

This is an Android question but also a Java question.

I seeted a custom thread exception handler in my activity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    public static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Thread thread;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler(this));
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(25);
                    crashMe(); //Makes app crash
                } catch (Exception exception) {

                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
    public void crashMe() {
       throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    public void crashMe2() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and as you can see, calling `crashMe()` after the timeout indeed makes the exception handler be called. However, some crashes of the Flutter Engine wont be catched by my handler and the app simply closes. Like this one:

```
2020-03-04 13:36:08.938 3901-3901/com.demo.flutter_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.demo.flutter_app, PID: 3901
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.DisplayAdjustments android.view.Display.getDisplayAdjustments()' on a null object reference
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1900)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1636)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7946)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1092)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:812)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

where an experimental flutter webview is used.

How can I absolutely catch all crashes? I want to be able to restart the application whenever it happens, but some crashes aren't handled.

**UPDATE:**

Here's another crash that it does not handle:

```
[+1520 ms] F/libc    (31305): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 31351 (RenderThread), pid 31305 (com.example.bug)
[ +184 ms] *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
[        ] Build fingerprint: 'Dragon_Touch/M7/M7:9/PPR2.181005.003/ysq20190426:user/release-keys'
[        ] Revision: '0'
[        ] ABI: 'arm64'
[        ] pid: 31305, tid: 31351, name: RenderThread  >>> com.example.bug <<<
[        ] signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
[        ] Abort message: 'Failed to set damage region on surface 0x7a1391d400, error=EGL_BAD_ACCESS'
[        ]     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000007a77  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000000000000008
[        ]     x4  feff71647164636d  x5  feff71647164636d  x6  feff71647164636d  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
[        ]     x8  0000000000000083  x9  0000007abf876718  x10 fffffff87ffffbdf  x11 0000000000000001
[        ]     x12 0000007a1f57ebd0  x13 ffffffffffffffff  x14 ffffffffff000000  x15 ffffffffffffffff
[        ]     x16 0000007abf8b22b0  x17 0000007abf7f0298  x18 0000007a1f57e3ba  x19 0000000000007a49
[        ]     x20 0000000000007a77  x21 0000000000000083  x22 0000007a1a8a1bb0  x23 0000007a1f57f1b0
[        ]     x24 0000000000000000  x25 0000007a1a8a1b24  x26 0000007a1f57f198  x27 0000007a1a8a1b22
[   +2 ms]     x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000007a1f57eaf0
[   +1 ms]     sp  0000007a1f57eab0  lr  0000007abf7e4a50  pc  0000007abf7e4a7c
[  +82 ms] backtrace:
[        ]     #00 pc 0000000000021a7c  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+124)
[        ]     #01 pc 00000000000080f8  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+296)
[        ]     #02 pc 0000000000486e64  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::EglManager::damageFrame(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, SkRect const&)+180)
[        ]     #03 pc 0000000000480858  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::draw(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, SkRect const&, SkRect const&,
android::uirenderer::FrameBuilder::LightGeometry const&, android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue*, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, bool, bool, android::uirenderer::BakedOpRenderer::LightInfo const&,
std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::Re
[   +1 ms]     #04 pc 0000000000108728  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+192)
[        ]     #05 pc 0000000000485854  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
(_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+644)
[        ]     #06 pc 000000000043c5a8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+168)
[        ]     #07 pc 0000000000115e5c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+244)
[        ]     #08 pc 000000000000fb80  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
[        ]     #09 pc 00000000000830d4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
[        ]     #10 pc 000000000002337c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit - answer to comments**

Even if there is a `try - catch` clause the exception may be thrown either way - when your code implicitly or you explicitly throw an exception inside of a `catch` block it won't be handled by custom `UncaughtExceptionHandler`

All the exception that are not handled(have no `try - catch` wrapper) and have no custom `UncaughtExceptionHandler` will be handled by the default one.

In terms of Android, exceptions in C code is quite hard to handle and catch whatsoever - the best way for that is to propagate them to your android code and handle them there - but it only applies to your C code but not some third party libraries. If there is no such propagation and exception is terminal - the app will stop rapidly and unexpectedly without any proper error management even with default `UncaughtExceptionHandler`

The error you've just updated you question with is a bit different from both Java and C ones. As you can see it has occurred on RenderThread thus it is directly connected with the CPU and GPU execution of the code. In android there are several ways to work in such conditions: [`OpenGl`](https://www.opengl.org/), [`Vulkan`](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/), [`RenderScript`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute), [`OpenCl`](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/) etc.

Flutter framework use GPU rendering paradigm so it basically works as games work on smartphones. I can assume that it uses some of described technologies to render UI(I think it is `OpenGL` since it is supported by most devices out of the box, though it may be some combination).

The error you posted is basically a C error but it is an error in RenderThread thus it is caused by incorrect execution of command either by GPU or CPU.

Flutter can handle some of such errors in correct way and give you a human readable resolution. Not in this case though.

I am sorry mate, there is no way to catch this error. But it is not intended to be caught as well as `NullPoitnerException` - those exceptions indicate some problems that should be fixed by the developer but not hidden with simple relaunch of the app.

**Edit end**

The thing is - there is no such thing as "absolutely catch all crashes" in Java. And this is the intended behaviour of JVM.

While `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` should work in most cases, it will not work when:

- Another `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` is used somewhere outside of your code(or thread an uncaught exception has occurred on has its own handler)
- The exception you want to catch by it is handled - wrapped by `try - catch` clause
- You want to show something(dialog or toast) inside the custom `UncaughtExceptionHandler` - that is highly not recommended since if the exception occurred on UI thread the app might freeze and if the exception occurred on non UI thread - when trying to show dialog you will receive an uncaught exception instead, since you can show something only on UI thread.

There are more cases but those cannot be applied to Android since those are web specific cases.

Also flutter has it own exception handling mechanism - so the flutter framework exceptions may not be handled the way you expect with custom `UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

So basically there is no way to clearly catch all the exceptions in Android app. Even Crashlitycs fails to catch them all, and it uses native(C based) approach.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But if the app crashes, then it means there's no try catch, neither a uncaugthExceptionHandler for that thread, neither flutter has an exception handler. Or maybe it has some of these but it recognizes it's an unrecoverable crash and exits? It's less probable but is it the only explanation?

Comment: in other words: will all the crashes that have no try catch, neither a uncaugthExceptionHandler, be catched by my default uncaugth exception handler? What about crashes in C++ code called from java? Like segmentation fault ones?

Comment: I've updated the question with another crash that it didn't handle. I've followed the backtrace and the error, I think, is called here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/682573c/libs/hwui/renderthread/EglManager.cpp#307. This seems to be from the skia framework which is used in Flutter. So I guess it's an internal error on the flutter engine. Am i rigth? As I understood, the engine itself chooses to abort when it reaches that line because it doesn't know what to do anymore. It also looks like that I can't pass a handler in that case. Am I rigth?